# Convert ellipse in image to circle (warp ellipse to circle like a polygon warping to rectangle)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image of an ellipse and if an image has ellipse i am finding it using findcontours() and then i want to convert this ellipse to a circle.

see the example

[image]

[image]

and i want transform each of them to like this

[image]

First I have applied canny edge detection.Then on this image findcontour() is applied.

I have found the ellipse using findcontours() to get all contours and get the required elliptical contour and then the i am using fitellipse() to get center, rotation angle and major and minor axis of ellipse.

I have then tried to rotate the image by the rotated angle and then scale height and width of image w.r.t minor and major axis(i.e. making major axis and minor axis length same) but also I am not getting the proper circular object image as above. There will be some rotation left/it will still be like an ellipse which will be near to circle or so.

```
     _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for c in contours:
        if len(c) >= 5:
            a = cv2.fitEllipse(c)
            (x, y), (MA, ma), angle = a
            area = (math.pi * MA * ma)/4
            if abs(x-image.shape[0]/2) <= 2 and abs(y-image.shape[1]/2) <= 2 and (area - cv2.contourArea(c)) < 50:
                screenCount = c
                width, height = MA, ma
                centerX, centerY = x, y
                ellipseAngle = angle
                print(width, height, centerX, centerY, ellipseAngle)
                # cv2.drawContours(img, c, -1, (0, 255, 0), 4)
                cv2.ellipse(img, a, (0, 0, 255), 2, 8)
                cv2.imshow("ellipse", img)
                break

    img = image.copy()
    if ellipseAngle < 90:
        rotatedImg = imutils.rotate(img, ellipseAngle)
    else:
        rotatedImg = imutils.rotate(img, -(ellipseAngle - 90))
```

Then i have scaled as per major and minor axis

after applying findcontour() i got these 2 contours for 1st image in the post

[image]
[image]

from these any contour is fine right? i am using the first contour from countour as per the code and fitellipse() gives me this ellipse

[image]

EDITED - If there are any better approach to solve this problem it would be helpful.

Comment: Without having a look at your code, this looks like the best case to use SVD (see animated gif in wikipedia)

Comment: @Veer Regarding your comment on my answer (which I'm going to delete after you possibly [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56663459/edit)): I'd advise you to choose another input example, like one you described in your comment, let's say some black ellipse with a red rectangle in it, to make clear, that you want to transform anything inside the ellipse as well (if I understood you correctly). From the initial problem statement, I wouldn't have thought that way (obviously, Ander did, but not me).

Comment: Why not just get the major axis diameter from end to end, divide by 2 and use that as a radius to draw a new black circle over the ellipse?

Comment: @fmw42 I need the information  inside the ellipse won't work if the ellipse is of different color.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have read the SVD wiki page but how can i get the matrices using the image of ellipse and also the approch explain in wiki is from circle to ellipse transformation but this problem is exactly the opposite

Comment: @CrisLuengo The images i provided are i first stretched the circle image that  i provided horizontally and vertically and i have applied rotation of just 15 degree to the right and 15 degrees to left which are the above 2 images i got. on these as per u if fit ellipse() is applied on these its somewhat near 40 to 45 degrees.

Comment: @CrisLuengo As per the we are likely to get only one contour if i run the findcontour() and then checked number of contours its 2 i.e. 2 contours around the same ellipse but with different points i have updated those images in question for reference.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sry fot that. The thresh is output image of not just thresholding. I have used canny edge detection. thresh is output of canny edge detection.

Comment: You've edited the question, asking for a better approach. It would be nice if you could leave a comment under my answer saying why it is not useful to you. I'm getting the expected output from it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I haven't seen your answer. I added that as i thought my approach may be wrong so if anyone can suggest a different approach than what i have done it would help i thought. Will go through your solution and update

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues I can see in the code:

1. You are using an edge detection algorithm, and getting the contours of the result. This is OK in principle, but it leads to an image that has two contours: one for the inner edge and one for the outer edge of the edge detection result. It is easier to just threshold the image and obtain a single edge. Though if the image gets more complex an edge detection might be relevant. Indeed, any one of the two contours you obtain should be useful.
2. The line `if abs(x-image.shape[0]/2) <= 2 and abs(y-image.shape[1]/2) <= 2 and (area - cv2.contourArea(c)) < 50` is very restrictive, it didn't trigger for the second image for me.
3. Rotating by `-(ellipseAngle - 90)` if the angle is negative is strange. You should rotate all ellipses in the same way.

The code below produces a circular output for both ellipse images shown in the question. I think that the ellipse parameters determined this way are not very precise, but it looks like they're good enough for this application.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('im1.png',0)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
params = cv2.fitEllipse(contours[0])
angle = params[2]
scale = params[1]
scale = scale[0]/scale[1]

M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((img.shape[0]/2, img.shape[1]/2), angle, 1)
# Let's add the scaling too:
M[:,0:2] = np.array([[1,0],[0,scale]]) @ M[:,0:2]
M[1,2] = M[1,2] * scale # This moves the ellipse so it doesn't end up outside the image (it's not correct to keep the ellipse in the middle of the image)

out = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, img.shape, borderValue=255)
cv2.imshow('out',out)
cv2.waitKey()
```

---

Using [PyDIP](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib) (I'm an author) you can get a more precise measure in the idealized case of the OP by not thresholding, and using the grey-values around the edges of the ellipse to get a more precise fit. We compute the second order central moments of the image, and derive the ellipse parameters from those. It is important here that the background is exactly 0, and that the foreground (ellipse pixels) are uniform in intensity except at the edge, where the intermediate grey-values add information about the sub-pixel location of the edge.

```py
import PyDIP as dip
import numpy as np

img = -dip.ImageRead('im1.png').TensorElement(0) # We use the inverted first channel
params = dip.Moments(img).secondOrder
M = np.array([[params[0],params[2]],[params[2],params[1]]])
d, V = np.linalg.eig(M)
d = np.sqrt(d)
scale = d[0]/d[1]
angle = np.arctan2(V[1,0],V[0,0])

img = dip.Rotation2D(img, -angle)
img = dip.Resampling(img, [scale, 1])
img.Show()
```